# Create Github Actions choice input options with key and value

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to create a GitHub Action that manually runs database migrations for different environments.

On the documentation I found a way to set the data source URL using option inputs, as follows

```
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      dataSourceUrl:
        description: 'Data source URL for each environment'
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
          - jdbc:postgresql://10.xxx.xxx.xx:5433/database_dev
          - jdbc:postgresql://10.xxx.xxx.xx:5433/database_test
          - jdbc:postgresql://10.xxx.xxx.xx:5433/database_stage
          - jdbc:postgresql://10.xxx.xxx.xx:5433/database
```

But the best way I image doing it would be if the options were a key/value pair, so on the GitHub UI it would show options like Dev, Tests, Stage and Prod instead of the URL.

Would be something like:

```
options:
          - option1:
            - key: dev 
            - value: jdbc:postgresql://10.xxx.xxx.xx:5433/database_dev
          - option2:
            - key: test
            - value: jdbc:postgresql://10.xxx.xxx.xx:5433/database_test
```

Does anyone knows how I can do that?

Comment: I think your best bet is to use e.g. `dev` as input and then do the mapping in a small bash script step.

Comment: What you want to achieve can't be done natively. However, there is a workaround where you could use 4 options (Dev, Tests, Stage and Prod) and then have a setup job in the workflow, where you would set the database value according to the option, and set it as output to use the rest of the workflow jobs (using the `needs` field).